# Can't pass header in Python client generated by OpenAPI Generator

Tags: python, openapi, openapi-generator, amadeus

With the help of [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) I generated a Python client for the Amadeus [Travel Restrictions API spec](https://github.com/tsolakoua/amadeus-open-api-example/blob/master/TravelRestrictions_v2_swagger_specification.json).

According to the [README](https://github.com/tsolakoua/amadeus-open-api-example/blob/master/covid19/README.md) generated, I understand that I can pass headers with the `header_params` parameter but I receive the following error:

```bash
TypeError: g_et_covid_report() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header_params'
```

Below you can check my code:

```py
import openapi_client
from openapi_client.apis.tags import covid19_area_report_api
from openapi_client.model.disease_area_report import DiseaseAreaReport
from openapi_client.model.error import Error
from openapi_client.model.meta import Meta
from openapi_client.model.warning import Warning
from pprint import pprint

configuration = openapi_client.Configuration(
    host = "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2"
)

with openapi_client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    api_instance = covid19_area_report_api.Covid19AreaReportApi(api_client)

    query_params = {
        'countryCode': "US",
    }
    
    header_params = {
    'Authorization': "Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    }
    try:
        api_response = api_instance.g_et_covid_report(
            query_params=query_params,
            header_params=header_params
        )
        pprint(api_response)
    except openapi_client.ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling Covid19AreaReportApi->g_et_covid_report: %s\n" % e)
```

I've been checking the library and also OpenAPI Generator project on GitHub but I still can't find a way to pass header parameters which I need in order to authorise my API call.

Comment: can you please open an issue via https://github.com/openapitools/openapi-generator/issues/new for tracking and we'll look into it? thanks.

Comment: Have you had a resolution for this issue?